# error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, recovery-mode

Is it possible to authorize the device while it's in Recovery Mode (Stock Recovery)?

My device has Marshmallow 6.0 and is authorized in normal boot mode, but unfortunately, it can't be authorized when reboot to recovery.

When i type in Recovery

```
adb shell
```

it keeps saying:

```
error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

there is an option in recovery menu called "Mount System", and I want to use adb in order to delete some system apps maybe!

Comment: Trying  the "mount system" option and delete some system apps

Comment: @beeshyams Agreed on the duplicate.